# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement (Python, MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I get an error on the following Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='DB')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

Name = "James"
Department = "Finance"
StartYear = 2001
CurrentPos = 2001
Link = ""

add_user = ("INSERT INTO DB.tbluser "
       "(username, department, startyear, currentpos, link) "
       "VALUES (%s, %s, %d, %d, %s)")
data_user = (Name, Department, StartYear, CurrentPos, Link)
cursor.execute(add_user, data_user)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

The error message is

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Do you understand why?

Comment: To use `?` instead of `%x` in the prepared statement you could `cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=true)`

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The parameter marker is `%s` not `%d`.

```
add_user = """INSERT INTO DB.tbluser 
              (username, department, startyear, currentpos, link) 
              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
```

Note that the [parameter markers](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) used by `mysql.connector` may look the same as the `%s` used in Python string formatting but the relationship is only coincidental. Some database adapters like `oursql` and `sqlite3` use `?` as the parameter marker instead of `%s`.

Comment: I thought they would be %d since they were numbers. But still same error when using %s and even when removing the two year-variables.

Comment: That's really curious. To debug, you could stop the `mysqld` server, then restart it with logging enabled: `mysqld --log=/path=/to/myquery.log`. Rerun the script, then look inside `/path/to/myquery.log` to see what SQL statement is being sent to the server. That should give us a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Restarting the server seems to have done the work... Sorry about wasting your time!

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score 1):

**Ok here is my solution:**

the %d's need to be %s's

the ''' works for multiple lines so does a +" at the start of a line and a "\ at the end
but that is not this issue here

I find sometimes the cursor.execute(query, values) or in your case the cursor.execute(add_user, data_user) buggy sometimes.. so I attach the values directly to the query.

You do this by first moving your data_user above the add_user. Then you add %values at the end of the query string (in your case %data_user). This will allow you to preform a nice little print(add_user) before the cursor.exec(add_user) command to look for other bugs.

```
        import mysql.connector

        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
              user='root', 
              password='',
              host='127.0.0.1',
              database='DB')

        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        Name = "James"
        Department = "Finance"
        StartYear = 2001
        CurrentPos = 2001
        Link = ""

        data_user = (Name, Department, StartYear, CurrentPos, Link)

        add_user = '''(INSERT INTO DB.tbluser 
        (username, department, startyear, currentpos, link) 
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s))'''%data_user


        cursor.execute(add_user)
        cnx.commit()
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
```

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score 0):

If Number of column and number of value mismatch than throw this error  **Error Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement**

you should avoid %d inside value

**Incorrect Code**

```
data = [('sundar','pichai','343434343','CEO'),('elon','musk','3434354545433','FOUNDER')]
    sql = "INSERT INTO user(firstname,lastname,phone_number,profession) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
```

**Correct code**

```
data = [('sundar','pichai','343434343','CEO'),('elon','musk','3434354545433','FOUNDER')]
    sql = "INSERT INTO user(firstname,lastname,phone_number,profession) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

Answer (score -1):

add_user = '''("INSERT INTO DB.tbluser "
       "(username, department, startyear, currentpos, link) "
       "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")'''

=> you are using multi line statement so use triple single quotation marks here
and use %s to represent passing value as string then that will works because %d is not supported by mysql to pass value

Comment: it is not exactly clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to insert a single line or multi line using this SQL query? Where are you using this query? along with the  or in the IDE?

You can modify your code like the following, add the parameter and execute the SQL
sql = "INSERT INTO DB.tbluser (username, department, startyear, currentpos, link) VALUES ('full name', 'new dept', '2020','http://xyz')"

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score -2):

```
import mysql.connector

def login(self,name,password):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="Cyber@123",database="mydata")
    if(db):
        print("connection successfull")
    else:
        print("faild")
    query = db.cursor()
    syntext = """insert into login(use_name,psd) values(%s,%s)"""
    value = (name,password)
    query.execute(syntext,value)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: It may be more helpful if you could briefly explain why/how your solution works.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score -3):

use single quotations

```
sql = 'insert into Student (id, fname, lname, school) values(%s, %s, %s , %s)'
values = (4, "Gaddafi", "Adamu", "Informatic")

a.execute(sql, values)

mydb.commit()
print(a.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```