# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement when using python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

hi I am doing the python mysql at this project, I initial the database and try to create the table record, but it seems cannot load data to the table, can anyone here can help me out with this

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost",user="root",password="asd619248636",database="mydatabase")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.excute=("CREATE TABLE record (temperature FLOAT(20) , humidity FLOAT(20))")
sql = "INSERT INTO record (temperature,humidity) VALUES (%d, %d)"
val = (2.3,4.5)
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

and the error shows     "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: You're creating the table every time (or attempting to)? Does the table already exist? If not, that would presumably be where it is failing.

Comment: Based on the mysql documentation (https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/), you should be initializing the cursor to be a prepared statement, like `mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)`

Comment: The table record exists since i checked by the other statement already, what i concerned about the error maybe is the insert method

Comment: I'd try `sql = "INSERT INTO record (temperature,humidity) VALUES (%s, %s)"`

Comment: From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) "The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style)."

Comment: yeah that works but i dont understand why i need to set value as string , the input should be floating number

Comment: I'd ask the developers of the library why. Oh and `%d` is for integers, `%f` is for floats in python string formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement (Python, MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818155/not-all-parameters-were-used-in-the-sql-statement-python-mysql)

Comment: %s is used because the operation is parameter substitution as specified in PEP-249, the DB-API spec, not string formatting.  The similarity is unfortunate.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the following should fix your problem:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO record (temperature,humidity) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("2.3","4.5") # You can also use (2.3, 4.5)
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
```

The database API takes strings as arguments, and later converts them to the appropriate datatype.  Your code is throwing an error because it isn't expecting `%d` or `%f` (int or float) datatypes.

For more info on this you can look [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

Comment: Can you edit to explain *why* that change fixes the problem? You're not teaching anyone anything without providing details about why that change is needed.

Comment: @Jane, the `val = (2.3, 4.5)` as floats will work just fine. The library being used only supports `%s` or `%(name)s` for parameter placeholders thus the SQL should use `%s`. See my comment above.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, I'll make a note of that in an edit.  You can also pass them as strings.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score 1):

simply change insert method to

```
sql = "INSERT INTO record (temperature,humidity) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```

then it works fine

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score -1):

This works for me.

```
# Insert from dataframe to table in SQL Server
import time
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# create timer
start_time = time.time()
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


df = pd.read_csv("C:\\your_path_here\\CSV1.csv")

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    r'SERVER=Excel-Your_Server_Name;'
    r'DATABASE=NORTHWND;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1([Name],[Address],[Age],[Work]) values (?,?,?,?)', 
                    row['Name'], 
                    row['Address'], 
                    row['Age'],
                    row['Work'])
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```